# Identifying this SMD capacitor

Tags: capacitor, identification, surface-mount

I would like to ask you for help with identify one capacitor at photo below (can't find it). I got GTX 1080 Ti to my hand with torn out capacitor on VRM. I am looking for the identical one. Can any one point me to which one it is, or advice to closest similar one?

size is : 7,5 x 4,35 x 1,9mm

[image]

Comment: What size is it?

Comment: size is : 7,5 x 4,35 x 1,9mm

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the case I am thinking you have a tantlum cap.

I agree it is likely a 16V 47uF

By your measurements I am thinking it is a 2917 package.

Here are some options that Digi-Key carries.
https://www.digikey.com/short/pb4vjm

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking its an electrolytic capacitor - The silver marking indicates the positive polarization.

The C indicates the voltage rating, in this case 16V

I'm thinking the 475E is 47*10^5 pF so 4,7 uF

Im have no idea about the size. You can find some information about the size here

I would see if I could measure the capacitance with a multimeter or something similar.

[SMD cap size info](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/electronic_components/capacitors/smd-smt-surface-mount-capacitor.php)